# Content Type Fields, populate field with usable data when adding new content

Tags: 7, entities

Trying to build a site that majoritly just uses Views and data structures defined within Drupal itself (aka: almost no programming on my end, though if it boiled down to it I will)

Trying to make a Music Album manager. Each album is a content type, and each track is a content type. I have in the Track content type a field called "Album" as a drop-down list which I wish to populate with existing Album records.
Problem is, I have no idea how I'm supposed to do that..

Is there a method? is there a module? is there anything I can do? There must be a way somewhere, I would hate to have to drop the entire process here and start from scratch again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry you don't need to start again, this is such a common use case there are actually 3 modules out there that you can choose between.

- [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference)
- [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) (can be considered deprecated in favour of entity reference).
- [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) (allows for complex relationships, probably overkill for your case)

All 3 will allow you to add a field to your track content type that references an album node. You can choose from a select list, radio/check buttons or autocomplete widget out-of-the-box but I'm sure there are add-ons available if you need them.

Comment: References can IMHO be considered deprecated in favor of Entity Reference already, which can now do everything that References can and more (e.g. integration with Views, which wasn't possible before).

Comment: @Berdir Good to know, I'll stop using references now then :)